# TCL script to access structure elements

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL programming. Can someone guide me to access the structure variables in the called procedure (SAV_DATA)?

```
struct_typedef XYZ {struct
  {ulong a}
  {ulong b}
}

proc SET_DATA {} {
  struct_new x XYZ

  set x(a) 1
  set x(b) 2

  SAV_DATA x
}

proc SAV_DATA {ARG1} {
  //How do i access the structure variables in this procedure
}
```

Comment: I'd love to know what `struct_typedef` is. Is it a library? If it is, which it is would be _very_ relevant to your question!

Comment: I think struct_typedef is from a library (tclstruc.dll). Using upvar i can access the elements I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

struct_typedef must be a procedure defined elsewhere in your code. Also struct_new. You need to include that function as well or link to where it comes from if it is a public library. `info body struct_typedef` will help if you cannot locate the function. However, most likely it just defines a Tcl array so your `struct_new x XYZ` probably sets `x` to be an array. In which case when you call SAV_DATA you are passing the array *name* to ARG1. The simplest method to examine the contents is usually so upvar the array:

```
proc SAV_DATA {varname} {
    upvar $varname x
    puts $x(a)
    puts $x(b)
}
```

The `upvar` call will make the local variable `x` refer to the named variable in the parent procedure context - so we have what C++ programmers might call a reference to the array in the callers context.

If we don't use upvar, then you have to expand the variable name first then access the array element. Such code looks like this:

```
proc SAV_DATA {varname} {
    puts [set [set varname](a)]
    puts [set [set varname](b)]
}
```